# How to group a string into strings of length four?

Tags: haskell

How can I turn a string into a lists of repeated characters with length no more than four?  I made a function that reduces the length of the String to four, and I called it `chop`, but I need a function that separates the strings into lists of repeated characters and then use `chop`.

Let's call the function that does this task `lsi`, so that the result of `lsi "aaaaaaabbb"` 
is `["aaaa", "aaa", "bbb"]`. I have tried using the following function to implement `lsi`, but it doesn't chop the string down to four characters.

```
run [] = []
run (x:xs) = (x : takeWhile (==x) xs)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import Data.List (group)

chop _ [] = []
chop n xs = take n xs : chop n (drop n xs)

lsi :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [[a]]
lsi = concatMap (chop 4) . group
```

I defined chop slightly differently. It simply divides a list into a list of lists, with the given maximum length for each sublist.

```
ghci> chop 2 "abcdefgh"
["ab","cd","ef","gh"]
```

After that `lsi` is a simple matter of composing `group` and `concatMap` with `chop 4`.

```
ghci> lsi "aaaaaabbbbbccc"
["aaaa","aa","bbbb","b","ccc"]
```

I suggest you [Hoogle](http://haskell.org/hoogle) `group` and `concatMap` if you aren't familiar with them yet.

Comment: There's `splitAt` which can be used in place of `(take, drop)`, and so if you use `{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}` you get the nice-looking `chop _ [] = []; chop n (splitAt n -> (h, t)) = h : chop n t`.

Comment: @ephemient sweet, I didn't know about that pragma. The Data.Sequence view methods make a lot more sense now :)

Answer (score 0):

The `group` function groups your list into chunks of equal elements.
For your `chop` function there is a nice generic implementation mentioned in [The Haskell Cafe](http://www.opensubscriber.com/message/haskell-cafe@haskell.org/3089100.html).

The complete solution to your problem looks like this:

```
import Data.List (group)

chop :: ([a] -> (b, [a])) ->  [a] ->  [b]
chop _ [] = []
chop f as = b : chop f as'
  where (b, as') = f as

lsi :: String -> [String]
lsi = concat . map (chop $ splitAt 4) . group

main = putStrLn $ show $ lsi "aaaaaaabbb"
```